# Can no-longer run Win-Acme (Lets encrypt on Windows Server 2019

Tags: .net-core, lets-encrypt

After checking on a report from an expiring certificate that i no longer can run the Win-Acme (v2.1.2.630 (x64, Release)) client on several Windows Server 2019 servers.

They all fail with the following error:

D:\Lets-Encrypt>wacs.exe

Failure processing application bundle.
Failed to determine location for extracting embedded files
DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR is not set, and temp-directory doesn't exist or is not readable/writable.
A fatal error was encountered. Could not extract contents of the bundle

Is this some kind of .net core issue?

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the servers? it actually solved the issue for us

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with wacs on Win 2019 server. Just add DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR as Environment Variable (for current user or globally) to desired directory and ensure you have write permissions.

Comment: This works - however something must have recently changed in .NET Core 3.1.3  since this behavior was not happening for us in previous builds.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by running the command as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was I needed to install the latest .NET Core Runtime; I only had 2.x installed. Not sure if this will work for everyone of course, but definitely something to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing the latest version of WinAcme.